# Background properties not working from stylesheet

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to set a background image for all buttons in the application, when I set it via FXML file it works fine but when I use CSS stylesheet to set it it doesn't work although some other properties are working fine from stylesheet like fonts properties.

This is my stylesheet code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'AdvertisingExtraBold';
    src: url('/fonts/AdvertisingExtraBold.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Droid Arabic Kufi';
    src: url('/fonts/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Naskh';
    src: url('/fonts/droid-naskh.ttf');
}

.label {
    -fx-font-family: 'Kufi';
}

.button .text {
    -fx-font-family: 'AdvertisingExtraBold';    // This is working fine
    -fx-background-image: url('shutdown.png');  // This is not
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;           // This is not
    -fx-background-size: 40;                    // This is not
}
```

But when I apply it in the FXML file like below it works fine:

```
<Button  prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="40" style="-fx-background-image: url('shutdown.png');-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;-fx-background-size: 40;" />
```

It's the same code, why it doesn't work from stylesheet?

What's the difference and why font properties are working while background-image aren't?

I'm loading the style sheet successfully like that :

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Button` has background properties; the `Text` node it contains does not. The inline style works because you are applying the rules to the button. So

```css
.button .text{
    -fx-font-family: 'AdvertisingExtraBold';  
}
.button {
    -fx-background-image: url('shutdown.png');
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    -fx-background-size: 40;
}
```

will work.

Comment: Can I ask how to apply it for specific buttons via style sheet file?

Comment: @Mohammad Give the button an id and use the id as the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try following in css file as you trying to override button style.

```
-fx-background-image: url('shutdown.png') !important; 
-fx-background-repeat: no-repeat !important;           
-fx-background-size: 40 !important;
```